# Will eventbridge throttle lambda if there are so many events in a batch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I am using AWS Eventbrige eventbus as source to trigger a lambda function. Eventbirge is not low latency service and it sends event to lambda around every 250ms. If there are multiple events in one batch, it will trigger lambda multiple times, one event for one lambda invocation.

My question is if there are more than 1000 events happens in one batch, since eventbridge tries to invoke lambda more than 1000 times, will it throttle lambda (maximum throughput in lambda is 1000)? If yes, how can I solve the issue? If not, what is the behaviour for the extra events? Will they be cached or dropped?

Answer (score 6):

EventBridge will retry failing invocations, such as due to throttling, for up to 24 hours, so events persist for that time and do not get dropped.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/cloudwatch-limits-eventbridge.html#invocations-limits

> If the invocation of a target fails due to a problem with the target service, account throttling, etc., new attempts are made for up to 24 hours for a specific invocation.

Comment: What is the retry interval? if I am using SQS, will it queue the events rather than retry?